DateTime.TryParseExact returns false when trying to parse German date values
I'm trying to parse the string "Sam Mär 24 03:58:38 2024" which is in German format and using the following code, it always returns false and I cannot figure out why.
DateTime.TryParseExact("Sam Mär 24 03:58:38 2024", 
                       "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", 
                       new CultureInfo("de-DE"), 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, out result)

I'd expect the string to be parsed and required datetime values extracted for the same.

That doesn't seem to be a valid date.  2024-Mar-24 was a Sunday (Sonntag) not a Saturday (Samstag) as listed in your input.

DateTime.TryParseExact is working fine
string s = new DateTime(2024, 3, 24, 3, 58, 38).ToString("ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
Console.WriteLine(s);
DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", new CultureInfo("de-DE"), DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime result);
Console.WriteLine(result);

But your input string is incorrect.  The actual string corresponding to this DateTime is

So März 24 03:58:38 2024

the three-letter month is also accepted

So Mär 24 03:58:38 2024

The wrong day-of-week causes the failure.

You can identify the problem by performing the reverse operation, calling DateTime.ToString to format the expected DateTime value with your format string:
new DateTime(2024, 3, 24, 3, 58, 38).ToString("ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", new CultureInfo("de-DE"))

The result is "So März 24 03:58:38 2024". This differs from your input string as follows:

The abbreviated day of week is expected to be "So" instead of "Sam".
The abbreviated month is expected to be "März" (the genitive form) instead of "Mär". However, Mär is also accepted.


I don't think genitive is relevant here, März is the spelling for all cases.

@BenVoigt: That's not the case in .NET. CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE").DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames[2] gives "Mär" instead of "März", and new DateTime(2024, 3, 24).ToString("MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")) yields "Mär 2024" instead of "März 2024".

Although "MMM" without "d'" does produce a difference, and in grammar would shift to genitive case, the actual output doesn't appear to be that, it appears to just be using three letter abbreviations for all months.  In any case the three letter abbreviation should always be accepted by TryParseExact for "MMM".

For example, "der Juni" becomes "des Junis", but .NET doesn't generate that for "MMM d".  .NET appears to have two sets of abbreviations, one to three letters and one to four letters, and ParseExact accepts both.

AbbreviatedMonthNames for de-DE includes three-letter abbreviations only, but AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames includes a mixture of three- and four-letter names/abbreviations: "Jan.", "Feb.", "März", "Apr.", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "Aug.", "Sept.", "Okt.", "Nov.", "Dez." ParseExact is permissive when parsing MMM and accepts either the genitive or non-genitive form.

.NET produces Sep. not Sept.   The "genitive" are actually simply all four (hard upper limit) character abbreviations, with no other difference.  And they are really not genitive, as four character abbreviation of "des Junis" shall be Jun., not Juni.  And "des Maies/Mais" should become either Mai. or Mais, but .NET produces Mai.  Nope, not genitive at all.

new DateTime(2024, 9, 1).ToString("d MMM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")) returns "1 Sept." (at least on .NET 6), not "1 Sep". It's true that the actual month names aren't genitive, but the only reason that ParseExact accepts "März" here is that it's in AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames. Were it not, ParseExact would accept "Mär" only. That's why I mentioned the genitive form in my answer.
